Firefox: Hover actions not working in fullscreen mode
This bothers me for over a year now: When a Firefox window goes to fullscreen, the hover actions don't work anymore. In the fullscreen window itself and in any other window. I switched off any extensions and plugins, I updated several times. The issue stays. What's the best way to find out, what the reason for this is? The GIF below shows the behavior on a youtube page. I cannot click any video controls there as the hover actions only appears when the mouse is moving. As soon as the mouse stops, the hover attribute seems to vanish. (INTEL macOS 14.4.1/Firefox 124.0.2)


Have you tried a different browser like Edge, Opera, Brave, etc.?

Yes. They work fine.

That would narrow it down to a FireFox issue, not macOS.
